# Usage of the word "envy"

Tags: word-usage

If Joe envied something, would it be proper to call that something "Joe's Envy"? Considering the usage in a team name but I am not sure if it makes sense.

Comment: Yes.  Envy can be used as a noun that represents the object of one's envy.

Comment: Yeah, you could probably fill in the blank ("Joe's _______ ) with any of the seven deadly sins (viz., wrath, greed, sloth, pride, lust, envy, and gluttony)!  [Let's see, Joe's lust?  Check.  Joe's sloth?  Check.  Joe's gluttony?  Check.  Joe's pride?  Check.  Joe's wrath?  Check.  Joe's greed?  Yup.  All seven are covered quite nicely!]

Comment: Provided you were referring to the sins. Referring to external objects as being foci for them is not that easy. Would you refer to Joe's girlfriend as _Joe's lust_? And his bank account as _Joe's greed_? _Envy_ just doesn't work, except in fixed phrases, like _the envy of <insert group name>_, and even then it's said of a person, not the thing that causes it -- _You'll be the envy of everyone in the audience_ -- i.e, they'll envy you, not something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Envy is an emotion.  To envy is to experience that emotion in relation to something.  The object of envy is not envy.

However, from a literary perspective, you could still use "Joe's Envy" as a story or book title.

Just not as the object of that envy.

Comment: Formally, yes.  But informally it could be used, particularly for a team name or as part of a conversation. "Her beauty is my envy".

Comment: If Joe envied his brother's baseball team, calling the baseball team "Joe's Envy" would be like naming his car "Joe's Drive" because Joe drives it.  Or calling his breakfast "Joe's Eat" because that is what he ate.

Comment: But you could call a car your ride, and no one would bat an eye.  It doesn't work in every case, but there are certain cases where it does.  Though I'll concede it might not be proper grammar.

Comment: You know, you can do what you want, it's not up to me.  But a car is a ride, and an accepted neologism and colloguialism at that, but the object of Joe's enviousness is not his envy, no matter what you say.

Comment: Second definition. 

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/envy

Comment: *Love* is both a verb and a noun; "A love like mine" becomes "my love" which in turn becomes "Marilou's love". Likewise envy is a verb and a noun.

Comment: Take a look at Joe's ride. It is a mighty fine ride. I feel my envy rising

Comment: @Zibbobz: I think you've hit upon a major problem encountered when using dictionary definitions. The fact that one sense is defined: **envy** noun

**an object of envious feeling**: _Her intelligence made her the envy of her classmates._ does not mean that the two are interchangeable in every (or even most) constructions. The definition certainly holds for constructions _X was the envy of Y_, which are common, but does not guarantee that constructions of the form _X was Y's envy_ are considered acceptable.